# Retrieve image name from database within background: url

Tags: php, background-image

I want to use the image reference I made in the database as a background: url. I've made the design already => http://i49.tinypic.com/30ihudz.png In my current code I use div style in which I retrieve the image, but that doesn´t show up no image. Could somebody please guide me? Thanks in advance.

public function displayProduct()
        {

```
        $product = $this->db->query("SELECT id, title, description, price, filename FROM trips ORDER BY id");

            while ($row = $product->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                    $output .= '<div class="reisbox">';
                            $output .= '<div id="reis_insidebox1" style="background: url(\'img/content/'.$row['filename'].'\')" width="1000" height="500">';
                    $output .= '<div class="reis_textbox">';
                    $output .= '<h2>'.ucfirst($row['title']).'</h2>';
                            $output .= '<article>';
                            $output .=  ucfirst($row['description']);
                            $output .= '</article>';
                            $output .= '</div>';
                    $output .= '<div class="rightboxx">';
                    $output .= '<div class="reis_price_box">';
                            $output .= '<div class="reis_price_box_text">';
                            $output .= '&euro;'.$row['price'];
                            $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '<div class="more_box">';
                            $output .= '<a href="index.php?page=reis.php&pid='.$row['id'].'"><p>Lees meer..</p></a>';
                            $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .='<br />';
                            $output .= '<div id="add">';
                            $output .='<a href="index.php?page=cart.php&action=add&id='.$row['id'].'"><p>Add to cart</p></a>';
                            $output .= '</div>';
                    $output .= '</div>';
                            $output .= '</div>';
                }
                return $output;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

C:/ is not an URL since it has no protocol (like file: or http:). Make the path point towards a file inside the htdocs folder like

```
"http://localhost/images/"
```

or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited that, but the problem is still not resolved

Comment: When you look at the page source, do you see the correct URL in the code? If so, cut it out and paste the URL directly into the address bar of your browser. If this doesn't show the image your browser cannot access the file.